# Как правильно тут объявить деструктор?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, деструктор

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test{
    private:
        int a, b, c;
    public:
        Test(){
            a=12;
            b=10;
            c=1999;
        };
        Test(int a, int b, int c){
            a=a;
            b=b;
            c=c;
        }
        Test(const Test &test):
            a(test.a), b(test.b), c(test.c){
                cout<<"Copy constructor worked here!\n";
            }
};
int main() {
    Test first;
    Test second(27,12,2029);
    Test copysecond(second);
    return 0;
}
```

Оглашаю вот такой класс и я не очень понимаю, как написать деструктор правильно и его объявить. Меня смущает, что у меня тут три конструктора или на это всё равно и достаточно просто прописать: `~Test(){...};`?

Comment: В вашем случае деструктор и не нужен (он создается неявно), тк нет выделения динамической памяти, которую нужно было бы очищать. А то что 3 конструктора, ничего страшного, бывает и больше.

Comment: Самодельный деструктор не нужен, и самодельный копирующий конструктор тоже не нужен.

Comment: Возможно это химический пример, но обратите внимание, что в вашем коде второй конструктор ничего не делает. Параметр, переданный в конструктор, присваивается сам в себя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да что пошла мода на *оглашенных*? Всегда были объявления...

В вашем конкретном случае — вообще никак. Сгенерированного компилятором достаточно.

Или можно явно сказать об этом:

```
~Test() = default;
```

Но, конечно, если очень хочется самому, то

```
~Test(){}
```

Ну, если вы хотите, чтобы конструктор что-то делал — дописывайте в фигурных скобках код. Но это все будут, так сказать, побочные действия. Никакой "обязательной программы" ***в вашем случае*** для деструктора нет.

Comment: "Да что пошла мода на оглашенных? Всегда были объявления..." - я предполагаю, что у человека русский язык не родной (или один из родных, но не основной). Есть как минимум один язык славянской группы, в котором "объявить" звучит примерно как "огласить". P.S. а, ну вы знаете)

Comment: @insolor Тогда уж "оголосити" ([оголосыты]). Просто для русскоязычного уха *оглашенный* потеряло достаточно давно свой прямой смысл (*проходящий катехизацию (оглашение), готовящийся принять таинство крещения*) и теперь означает "*человек, ведущий себя бестолково, шумно*". И поэтому *оглашенный деструктор* не может не вызвать (как минимум) улыбку...

Comment: Ну, я думаю у авторов вопросов русификация окончания этого слова произошла, а корень не изменился) Получилось все на русском кроме одного слова. Хотя может это диалектное что-то, типа южнорусское, но не слышал такого никогда, даже сразу не понял что это "объявить", пока ваш ответ не прочитал, хотя украинский достаточно хорошо знаю.